# How to write directly to a disk?

Tags: c

I am a amateur programmer in C programming, I know how to read data directly from a drive (file = fopen("//./D:", "r"); ). Now I want to write data to the disk directly using the same way by changing the second argument of the mentioned function  to "w". But it doesn't work even when I run the program as administrator. I was wondering:

1. How to write data directly to a drive or flash drive using C?
2. How the programs like Diskpart.exe write to a disk?

I am using Windows.

Comment: Please post [mcve], and define the "doesn't work" thing.

Comment: Don't ever do that unless you have considerable experience with file-systems and the inner workings of NTFS. A single byte written in the wrong place can destroy the whole disk.

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you mean b "directly" and explain why you want that, in contrast to e.g. "conveniently", "safely", ...

Comment: If you're in user mode, you cannot get around the operating system.

Comment: @GovindParmar That comment is quite close to an answer. Am I guessing correctly that you also wait for a clarification of "directly"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows imposes [special requirements for direct write access to disk volumes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942448/changes-to-the-file-system-and-to-the-storage-stack-to-restrict-direct). You have to have administrative privileges *and* you have to take extra steps to demonstrate to the operating system that you are not going to overwrite the contents of a mounted file system (which could cause the entire computer to crash).  `fopen("//./D:", "w")` does not take those extra steps.  It appears to me that you can't do this with `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, etc; you need to use the [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea), ReadFile, WriteFile, etc operating system primitives directly.

(As discussed in the Q&A that this is now closed as a duplicate of, the first of these "extra steps" is opening the device pathname for *read and write* access, even if you only mean to write -- `GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE` at the CreateFile level.  fopen mode `"w"` supplies only `GENERIC_WRITE` to CreateFile.  You also need to specify a particular disposition, sharing mode, file attributes, security attributes, etc.)